# order alphabetically and then create a new column starting from 1

Tags: r

```
Data <- c("Chelsea", "Arsenal", "Liverpool", "Brighton", "Fulham", "Tottenham", "Newcastle", "Wolverhampton", "Mancity", "Southampton")
```

I want to order the column alphabetically and then create a new group starting from 1, so the output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: `data.frame(Club = sort(Data), Group = seq_along(Data))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort` for your clubs and `row_number` to assign the values to group like this:

```r
Data<- c("Chelsea", "Arsenal", "Liverpool", "Brighton", "Fulham", "Tottenham", "Newcastle", "Wolverhampton", "Mancity", "Southampton")

library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(., c("Club" = ".")) %>%
  mutate(Club = sort(Club),
         Group = row_number())
#>             Club Group
#> 1        Arsenal     1
#> 2       Brighton     2
#> 3        Chelsea     3
#> 4         Fulham     4
#> 5      Liverpool     5
#> 6        Mancity     6
#> 7      Newcastle     7
#> 8    Southampton     8
#> 9      Tottenham     9
#> 10 Wolverhampton    10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Quinten, thank you for responding to this. Just want to add, in the data frame, the club names appeared more than once. So, it goes like this:

Answer (score 1):

Slightley adapted from @Quinten's answer:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tibble(Club = sort(Data)) %>% 
  mutate(Group= row_number())
```

```
 Club          Group
   <chr>         <int>
 1 Arsenal           1
 2 Brighton          2
 3 Chelsea           3
 4 Fulham            4
 5 Liverpool         5
 6 Mancity           6
 7 Newcastle         7
 8 Southampton       8
 9 Tottenham         9
10 Wolverhampton    10
```